# Strange thing with ceil() function rounding 49 up to 50

Tags: php, rounding

**TLDR: ceil(49) is resulting in 50.**

I have a code that reads a CSV file from our provider for updating our database's stock and prices.

I need to get the real product cost, but our price comes in a column, and the discount applied comes into another column, so I have to calculate the original price without discount. And here comes the weird thing.

The discount comes as "0.20" for a 20% discount.

This is the code I use:

```
while($line = fgetcsv($file, 0, ";")) {

    $currentSku = $line[$skuPosition];
    $currentPrice = $line[$pricePosition];
    $currentDiscount = $line[$discountPosition];

    // Only ovewrite price if a discount was applied to the price
    if(floatval($currentDiscount)!=0.0 && $currentDiscount!="") {

        // Convert 0.20 to 20
        $currentDiscount*= 100;

        // Replace 45,50 to 45.50
        $currentPrice = str_replace(",", ".", $currentPrice);

        // Original price without the discount
        $currentPrice = ($currentPrice * 100) / (100 - $currentDiscount);
    }

    // Round up price
    $currentPrice = ceil($currentPrice);

    // Generate sale price
    $currentPrice = $currentPrice * $priceMultiplier;
...
```

We have a product that costs 39.20, and has a 20% discount applied (0.20 column value).

The price without discount is 49, and the final sale price is 49*2 = 98.

**To make sure all values are correct**, you make a simple calculation:

If 49 is the 100% of the price...
X is the 20% to discount...

So:
20 * 49 = 980

980 / 100 = 9.8

So 9.8 is 20% of 49.

49 - 9.8 = 39.2

39.2 is the price listed on the provider's CSV.

Now, what is the final $currentPrice value of the code shown above? **100**

**It is calculating 50 * 2 = 100**

Now I placed some debugging code to see what's going on, so here we go again:
*('762.SSUBGMTVE' is the SKU of the product being proccessed)*

```
while($line = fgetcsv($file, 0, ";")) {

    $currentSku = $line[$skuPosition];
    $currentPrice = $line[$pricePosition];
    $currentDiscount = $line[$discountPosition];

    if(floatval($currentDiscount)!=0.0 && $currentDiscount!="") {

        if($currentSku=='762.SSUBGMTVE') {

            print("1 - ".$currentDiscount."<br>");
        }

        $currentDiscount*= 100;

        if($currentSku=='762.SSUBGMTVE') {

            print("2 - ".$currentDiscount."<br>");
        }

        $currentPrice = str_replace(",", ".", $currentPrice);

        if($currentSku=='762.SSUBGMTVE') {

            print("3 - ".$currentPrice."<br>");
        }

        $currentPrice = ($currentPrice * 100) / (100 - $currentDiscount);

        if($currentSku=='762.SSUBGMTVE') {

            print("4 - ".$currentPrice."<br>");
        }
    }

    $currentPrice = ceil($currentPrice);

    if($currentSku=='762.SSUBGMTVE') {

        print("5 - ".$currentPrice."<br>");
    }

    $currentPrice = $currentPrice * $priceMultiplier;

    if($currentSku=='762.SSUBGMTVE') {

        print("6 - ".$currentPrice."<br>");
    }
```

**This is the output:**

```
1 - 0.200000
2 - 20
3 - 39.20
4 - 49
5 - 50
6 - 100
```

I also tried adding a var_dump() before point debug "5":

```
        if($currentSku=='762.SSUBGMTVE') {

            var_dump($currentPrice);
            print("<br>** ".ceil($currentPrice)." **<br>");
        }

        $currentPrice = ceil($currentPrice);
        if($currentSku=='762.SSUBGMTVE') {

            var_dump($currentPrice);
        }

        if($currentSku=='762.SSUBGMTVE') {

            print("5 - ".$currentPrice."<br>");
        }
```

**And this is the output:**

```
1 - 0.200000
2 - 20
3 - 39.20
4 - 49
float(49)
** 50 **
float(50)
5 - 50
6 - 100
```

**And just as the final stroke**, just for fun:

```
if($currentSku=='762.SSUBGMTVE') {

    print("4 - ".$currentPrice."<br>");
    print("Check this out!: ceil(49) results in ".ceil(49).", but ceil(".$currentPrice.") results in ".ceil($currentPrice)." ... HAHAHA!!<br>");
}
```

**Result:**

```
4 - 49
Check this out!: ceil(49) results in 49, but ceil(49) results in 50 ... HAHAHA!!
```

**Could someone explain what is happening here, please?**

Maybe I'm completely blinded and there's something obvious right on my nose, but right now, it doesn't matter how many times I read the code and how many tests I do, but it doesn't make any sense.

Thanks!

Comment: Search for `what+every+programmer+needs+to+know+about+floating+point`

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't see how this is related (even if maybe it is). I even converted the variable to float, and it's just an integer with value 49.

Comment: It's not, really. When I try it, Line 4 becomes 49.000000000000007 - https://3v4l.org/jciUG

Comment: Please read warning part of this page: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php

Comment: FYI, you are unnecessarily complicating your math expression and a simplified version tested in virtually every version of PHP available on https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/ does not have this problem (at least with the given values). First, do not multiply anything by `100`, then use: ` $originalPrice = $currentPrice / (1 - $currentDiscount); // float(49)`

Answer (score 0):

Well.... https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/rounding.png

But in all seriousness, try this:

```
        $currentPrice = round(($currentPrice * 100) / (100 - $currentDiscount), 2);
```

You should end up with:
(39.20*100)/(100-20) = 49.00

If you don't, then try rounding `round($currentPrice, 2)` and see what you get after in the decimal places.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, the first round() did the trick. Also, I also tested what aynber did, and in PHP 8 the var_dump() returns indeed 49.00000000000001, instead of 49 like in PHP 7.
I knew that numbers like 10.00002 round to 11, but all my debugs showed "49", and that's what made me crazy.
PS: Tried to upvote your answer, but apparently I'm not worth it yet. Sorry.